# javascript / jquery creating a widget and using inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I've been playing with jquery for a week or two now and have something that resembles a hackey  overgrown example. It needs structure - I've worked with MVC before in java etc.. but im finding it hard to translate my large .js file into a number of distinct and logically separated views.

Within these views I'd like to be able create instances of certain widgets (its basically a div with a few buttons and some draggable behaviour). Obviously I'd like to be able to take advantage of inheritance as certain overgrown divs share the same sort of characteristics.

I know how to do this in Java but I cant seem to get my head within javascript. I can get to a point I can isolate a function call which in theory would hit something resembling a controller. At this point I proceed to check certain styles of a parent div etc. and then do a lot of appendTo's to a particular div thus creating my component.

In short how might I create a little widget and reference it within my jquery topped javascript. I'm not to sure about defining the object and creating event handlers etc for it. I guess I've been a hacker of js too long !

If you want an idea at what my current code resembles please see http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager I've basically added a number of other droppables and have to determine what div im dragging to and then do various things. Again its all kinda hackey. I'd like to make it a bit more engineered.

I've started to look at something like Backbone.js but I'd like advise on how to properly create my widgets.

Many thanks SO

Comment: Just to add to the discussion for future readers, you could also consider an MVVM strategy, like using Knockout JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also in the process of wrangling a dangerously growing jQuery application.

I found this article by Alex Sexton quite helpful: http://alexsexton.com/?p=51 which also says that you should not be afraid to create your own specialised jQuery plugins for your own page to structure your code (and your page).

I also read a lot of articles on class inheritance patterns in Javascript but I found Douglas Crockfords advice the wisest: "Because objects in JavaScript are so flexible, you will want to think differently about class hierarchies. Deep hierarchies are inappropriate. Shallow hierarchies are efficient and expressive." http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html.

So you might have an MVC type pattern at the back of your mind but try to implement it with as little object hierarchy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would not try to incorporate widget development w/ jQuery; it was never designed to be a framework solution, it's designed only as a DOM api.  This blog post by a fellow JS developer explains why jQuery is bad for this: http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/on-jquery-large-applications

I would recommend using a framework that already exists for creating modular widgets.  For jQuery apps, there exists JavascriptMVC (http://javascriptmvc.com/). I personally use the Dojo Toolkit which provides a robust and powerful widget framework known as Dijit. This framework provides everything you are asking for on top of a great DOM api that is as powerful and fast as jQuery w/ the Dojo Core libraries. Many enterprise applications use it to create their web UIs. It also provides support for il8n (internationalization), a11y (accessibility), and more.

Dojo Toolkit: http://dojotoolkit.org/

Writing Dijit Widgets: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#quickstart-writingwidgets

Basically, look beyond jQuery to other frameworks for widget development.

Comment: For the moment im stuck with the JQuery side of things - im going to install javamvc.  I guess while youve pointed me in a rough direction im kinda more after how do I take my overgrown div which by the looks of it will end up in some sort of div and make it into a resuable component/widget ?